# Creating key pairs from lists and appending to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, key-pair

I am trying to create key pairs from lists and then append them to a list of lists.  However it is returning an empty list.

```
  Combined = {}
  Awarded = []

  Keys = Contract_Keys + Details_Keys
  Values = Contract_Values + Details_Values
  #Create key pairs with multiple lists
  Combined = dict(zip(Keys, Values))

  #Append to the Awarded table
  Awarded.append(Combined)

  Final = pd.DataFrame(Awarded)
```

Note:  I have changed the code to the above so that I can actually return a non-empty set.  However the issue I am having now is that when I zip and dict the Keys and Values the result is odd:

Combined = dict(zip([a, b], [1,2])) is being returned as [a1:1, b2:2)  when it should be [a:1, b:2].  Any reason why the Value would be concatenated with the Key in the Key field?

Comment: You're making Combined into a dictionary after setting it asa list?

Comment: Did you want to use `extend`?

Comment: You might want to look into [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: I want to do whatever it takes to make a lists of the combined lists.  I am new to this so maybe its not possible?  Not sure what extend does but if that gets me to my end result than thats fine by me

Comment: Could you provide us sample data of input lists and expected output, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is what you where after but I was able to do it with list comprehensions?

```
Combined = {}
Awarded = []

#Created some test dictionaries
dictOne = {"k1" : "v1","k2" : "v2","k3" : "v3","k4" : "v4" }
dictTwo = {"k5" : "v5","k6" : "v6","k7" : "v7","k8" : "v8" }

#Got the keys
Contract_Keys = [keys for keys in dictOne]
Details_Keys = [keys for keys in dictTwo]

#Got the values
Contract_Values = [dictOne[values] for values in dictOne]
Details_Values = [dictTwo[values] for values in dictTwo]

########output###########
#['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'] 
#['k5', 'k6', 'k7', 'k8'] 

#['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4'] 
#['v5', 'v6', 'v7', 'v8'] 

#Concat lists
Keys = Contract_Keys + Details_Keys
Values = Contract_Values + Details_Values

#Combined lists into single dictionary
Combined = dict(zip(Keys, Values))

#Combined kvp from dict into a list of lists
Awarded = [[key, Combined[key]] for key in Combined]

#########output#########
#[['k1', 'v1'], ['k2', 'v2'], ['k3', 'v3'], ['k4', 'v4'], ['k5', 'v5'], 
#['k6', 'v6'], ['k7', 'v7'], ['k8', 'v8']]

#{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4', 'k5': 'v5', 'k6': 'v6', 
#'k7': 'v7', 'k8': 'v8'}
```